# Intermittent timeouts from an app that should never timeout (NOT an "R12 Request Timeout" error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, timeout

I've got a simple business Rails 3.2.13 app with a base of only one user, with very small Postgres DB tables, and very simple Active Record DB queries.  I'm running it on two dynos, zero workers, on the Unicorn web server.  The root page of the app typically loads in about 150 ms in development, and in under 1 s in production at Heroku.

EXCEPT, when it randomly times out.  I'm seeing timeouts in the log, but NOT the typical R12 Request Timeout.  The timeouts look like this:

```
2013-05-28T16:04:28.004290+00:00 app[web.2]: Started GET "/" for 72.28.209.197 at 2013-05-28 16:04:28 +0000
2013-05-28T16:04:44.225643+00:00 app[web.2]: E, [2013-05-28T16:04:44.225444 #2] ERROR -- : worker=2 PID:87 timeout (16s > 15s), killing
2013-05-28T16:04:44.238422+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path=/ host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com fwd="72.28.209.197" dyno=web.2 connect=7ms service=16240ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-05-28T16:04:44.255813+00:00 app[web.2]: E, [2013-05-28T16:04:44.255554 #2] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 87 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=2
2013-05-28T16:04:44.298023+00:00 app[web.2]: I, [2013-05-28T16:04:44.297643 #103]  INFO -- : worker=2 ready
```

When that request works, it looks like this:

```
2013-05-28T16:03:36.965507+00:00 app[web.1]: sequenceId="102642"] Started GET "/" for 72.28.209.197 at 2013-05-28 16:03:36 +0000
2013-05-28T16:03:37.388261+00:00 app[web.1]: sequenceId="102690"] Processing by OverviewController#index as HTML
2013-05-28T16:03:38.238877+00:00 app[web.1]: sequenceId="102707"]   Rendered overview/index.html.erb within layouts/application (315.8ms)
2013-05-28T16:03:38.311974+00:00 app[web.1]: sequenceId="102710"] Completed 200 OK in 924ms (Views: 432.4ms | ActiveRecord: 92.1ms)
2013-05-28T16:03:38.322786+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com fwd="72.28.209.197" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=1375ms status=200 bytes=136795
2013-05-28T16:03:42.625787+00:00 app[web.1]: sequenceId="102940"] Started GET "/assets/favicon.ico" for 72.28.209.197 at 2013-05-28 16:03:42 +0000
2013-05-28T16:03:58.753408+00:00 app[web.1]: sequenceId="104359"] E, [2013-05-28T16:03:58.753173 #2] ERROR -- : worker=2 PID:66 timeout (16s > 15s), killing
2013-05-28T16:03:58.801152+00:00 app[web.1]: sequenceId="104362"] E, [2013-05-28T16:03:58.800993 #2] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 66 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=2
2013-05-28T16:03:58.798722+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path=/assets/favicon.ico host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com fwd="72.28.209.197" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=16175ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-05-28T16:03:59.127150+00:00 app[web.1]: sequenceId="104397"] I, [2013-05-28T16:03:59.126795 #84]  INFO -- : worker=2 ready
```

Things to note: The request response time was 924 ms.  But then some kind of strange error happened after that.

This is what that request looks like in terms of [DB queries](https://gist.github.com/endymion/5b6dbe95d5d7c5db32be).  There is nothing exciting happening there, and those DB tables only contain a few hundred rows of data.  There is no reason why the response should take 1 second sometimes, and 15+ seconds on other times.  Here's the code for the extremely simple controller action:

```
class OverviewController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @current_event = Event.recent
    @areas = Area.order(:position)
    @reservations = Reservation.find(:all,
      :conditions => { :event_id => @current_event.id },
      :order => 'created_at DESC',
      :limit => 5)
  end

end
```

Here's the Event#recent method, just so that you can see that it's not doing anything that could potentially take 15+ seconds:

```
def self.recent
  Event.last || Event.create
end
```

I'm at a loss for how to get this app stabilized, other than moving it off of Heroku.  I don't know of any way to troubleshoot the problem, and I guess Heroku won't help.  Am I simply stuck?  Do I have any options for troubleshooting the problem other than moving the app to Engine Yard?

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems that problem with the request to favicon.ico, not with the index action. Try to add favicon. Also consider to remove project url from the logs, just in case :)

Comment: It's the request to the Rails app that is timing out.  I end up seeing the generic "Application Error" page.

Comment: I redacted the actual app URL, thanks for suggesting that.

Comment: `2013-05-28T16:03:58.798722+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path=/assets/favicon.ico host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com fwd="72.28.209.197" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=16175ms status=503 bytes=0` this line stated clearly that request can't get favicon, while action before is rendered fine.

Comment: is `config.assets.compile = false` in environments/production.rb?

Comment: Right, that was an example of what the logs look like when the action succeeds.  Just above that is an example of what the logs look like when it does not succeed.  The Rails action itself is timing out.  Sometimes it takes about a second (which seems very slow, compared to the 150 ms that it takes in development) and sometimes it takes over 15 seconds and causes a timeout.

Comment: Thank you, Jesse, it was set to true.  I set it to false, precompiled assets, and I completely removed the favicon links since I the app doesn't have one anyway.  Looks like that might have helped.  The current Heroku documentation for the Rails asset pipeline does not say to disable that, so I didn't.

Is it possible that the asset pipeline was choking on a missing image and then somehow causing the request response to stall?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing here helped, and this site is Heroku's technical support.  Paying $35/mo doesn't buy me any support, so I'm stuck and there is no way forward with Heroku.

So my answer to this problem is to move the app to Engine Yard.  I don't see that I have any other options.  Heroku is awesome when it works and it's a complete mystery with no technical support when it doesn't work.

Comment: I guess this problem turned out to be a good thing, because after I moved the app to the Engine Yard Cloud, the response time on that page went from 1s (when it worked) on Heroku to less than 200ms.  And it's only running on a "small" instance.  For the exact same $35/mo price as a Heroku dyno.

Comment: did engine yard end up being a good choice for you? I have a similar problem